# VARIABLE IN ORDER BY IN STORED PROCEDURE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to put variable in order by clause in a stored procedure but its returning an error.
the code is as follows;

```
SELECT ...
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.SQL_HANDLE) AS st
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
WHERE @where LIKE '%'+@search+'%'
ORDER BY CASE @ORDER
```

The error is;

```
'Msg 1008, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_ExecInfo2, Line 40
The SELECT item identified by the ORDER BY number 1 contains a variable as part of the expression identifying a column position. Variables are only allowed when ordering by an expression referencing a column name.'
```

Comment: You need to create Dynamic SQL

Comment: Maybe you can add ordering column and fill it conditionally - then ORDER BY that additional column. But this approach may have performance issues (conditional column is not indexed).

Comment: `LIKE '%@search%'`. I don't think that means what you think it means. _(Inigo Montoya)_ It looks like another case of _optimistic programming_. Variables should do what I want, sometimes values, sometime code, sometimes music, sometimes insert their values into string literals.

Comment: Yikes. This type of thing is very dangerous. http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to use a `variable` in `order by` clause, you need to make a string for your query and then execute it by `sp_execute_sql`

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = 'SELECT ... '+
'FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs '+
'CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.SQL_HANDLE) AS st '+
'CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp '+
'WHERE '+@where+' LIKE ''%'+@search+'%'''+
'ORDER BY '+@order

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: sql injection anybody? This works but if you post this type of thing you need to warn the user about sql injection.

Comment: @Sean Lange This and the recompile problem are why I try to avoid dynamic SQL at all. Also I a posted a link to a article comparing all the alternatives

Comment: Recompile problem? What does that mean? Also, I don't see any reference to an article or any other alternatives.

Answer (score 5):

For a small set of candidate orders;

```
ORDER BY 
  CASE @ORDER WHEN 1 THEN fld1 END,
  CASE @ORDER WHEN 2 THEN fld2 END,
  CASE @ORDER WHEN 3 THEN fld3 END
```

Comment: This way of doing it is secure. All the approaches with dynamic sql are a disaster waiting to happen. (you need to parse the @order variable and only  allow white-listed values.)

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially do something like this in the ORDER BY clause, but I think you are still going to have some issues with your WHERE clause.

```
ORDER BY 
        CASE @ORDER
            WHEN 'columnname1' THEN columnname1
            WHEN 'columnname2' THEN columnname2
        END
```

Answer (score 0):

As Reza said you cannot acomplish it this way. One way can be dynamic SQL but there are other alternatives. Also dynamic SQL have some pitfalls and you must plan a bit before going down with it (also be aware of SQL inject attacks!).

You can follow this link to a great and extensive article about a variety of thecniques about conditional SQL (conditional ordering included)

[Dynamic Conditional SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)